# JEditorPane.setText Shows Bottom of the Page

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

In a gui I created I have a JEditorPane that has the following operations during class construction:

```
    htmlPane = new JEditorPane();
    htmlPane.setEditable(false);
    htmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
    htmlPane.setText(Utils.startHtml);
```

Then during create GUI I do this:

```
jsp = new JScrollPane( htmlPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED );
        jsp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension((width/2)+100,height-85));
        rightPanel.add(jsp);
```

When I load new text into the JEditorPane via set text is scrolls to the botom:

```
htmlPane.setText(newHtml)
```

How do I prevent the scrolling to the bottom?  I want the top of the html shown.

Comment: not sure if is caused by setText, insert or append, from this code description, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable  with hardcoded value for `Document` for `JEditorPane` instead of `setText()`

Comment: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)htmlPane.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```